# Searching for an element in list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, search

I am trying to search for an element in a list of lists, and return the second element of that list.

I am new to programming and I want to search for a word in a list of lists that look like this:

```
list = [['592', 'Frillish', 'Water', 'Ghost', '335', '55', '40', '50', '65', '85', '40', '5', 'False']
['593', 'Jellicent', 'Water', 'Ghost', '480', '100', '60', '70', '85', '105', '60', '5', 'False']
['594', 'Alomomola', 'Water', '', '470', '165', '75', '80', '40', '45', '65', '5', 'False']
['595', 'Joltik', 'Bug', 'Electric', '319', '50', '47', '50', '57', '50', '65', '5', 'False']]
```

What I have now is something like :

```
def search(word):
    result_of_search = []
    for i in list:
        if word in i:
            result_of_search.append.......
```

This is the part where i get stuck. I want to return the second element in the list , if the word exist in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you should do:

```
[x[1] for x in lst if word in x]
```

Note that I have renamed your list to `lst` as `list` is a built-in.

In a function:

```
def search(word):
    return [x[1] for x in lst if word in x]
```

[Read](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) about list comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

I tried like below:

```
l = [['592', 'Frillish', 'Water', 'Ghost', '335', '55', '40', '50', '65', '85', '40', '5', 'False'],
['593', 'Jellicent', 'Water', 'Ghost', '480', '100', '60', '70', '85', '105', '60', '5', 'False'],
['594', 'Alomomola', 'Water', '', '470', '165', '75', '80', '40', '45', '65', '5', 'False'],
['595', 'Joltik', 'Bug', 'Electric', '319', '50', '47', '50', '57', '50', '65', '5', 'False']]

import itertools

def search(l,word):
    merged = list(itertools.chain(*l))

    if merged.count(word)== 0:
        print("not present")
    else:
        print(word,"--repeated times:", merged.count(word))
```

```
search(l,"apple")
```

```
ans: not present
```

```
search(l,"Water")
```

```
ans: Water --repeated times: 3
```